Calculating Area of Parcel/ Building Footprint
I am trying to calculate:

Total Parcel Area (Square feet)
Sum of the area (sq. ft.) for all the buildings on the parcel (building footprint of all structures including garages, clubhouse, common use structures)
Remaining area (sq. ft.), which is the estimate of the square footage of all other non-structure areas (parking lots, streets/medians, tennis courts, other paved areas, etc.)

I have a parcel layer provided by the County, a NearMap Basemap, and a building footprint. The building footprint doesn't align with the NearMap Basemap imagery, however, so I am trying to determine how to most accurately determine these areas.
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.2.


Calculate Geometry? but set your units correctly - NearMap Accuracy is dependent on version https://help.nearmap.com/kb/articles/250-accuracy [RMSEr is Root Mean Square Error) even fully ortho-rectified imagery has distortion.
